# jQuery if value is empty set it to 0 and validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Simple Question I just cant solve, I have the following function:

```
function finalCheck(){

        var result = true;
        jQuery("#carloan-form :input[type=text]").each(function() {

            if(!this.value){this.value = 0;}

            if(jQuery.isNumeric(this.value) && this.value>=0) {
                jQuery(this).parent().children('.cal-error').slideUp(300)
            }else{
                result = false;
                jQuery(this).parent().children('.cal-error').slideDown(300);
                jQuery('.cal-result').slideUp(300);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
```

basically the problem is `if(!this.value){this.value = 0;}` if there is no value i need to set it to zero before carrying on with the validating the form, but this only seems to take effect the second time i validate it.

So it all boils down to if i set an inputs value to 0 in the each loop, it only takes it into account after the function is done.

Here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQSA3/3/), Identical to my current problem, only on the second click will the proper value appear.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Is this (`finalCheck`) your validate function function, if so, then just do it before you call it.

Comment: I need it inside my loop though.

Comment: Not sure if I really understood your question.

Comment: My Apologies, Do you understand it now?

Comment: Are you saying `if(jQuery.isNumeric(this.value) && this.value>=0)` evaluates as false on the first entry, when `!this.value` evaluates true?

Comment: no what im saying is i want to set all inputs to zero if they are empty (if(!this.value){this.value = 0;}) and carry on with the validation process.

Comment: Based on your latest edit to the question, I think this *is* what you're saying is happening. But I don't see any reason for your code to do that. This JSFiddle for example, attempts to do more or less the same thing, and for me reports "It is OK" - http://jsfiddle.net/bQSA3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bQSA3/3/ okay this is identical to my problem, only on the second click of the button does the value appear.

Comment: That's because you are setting `finalValue` **before** calling `test()`. I've moved that line, and it now sets "0" on the first click. http://jsfiddle.net/bQSA3/4/

Comment: Thank you this solved everything. Perhaps Put it as an answer so i can mark it for future user who face this stupid issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you are *getting* the value, though this isn't evident in your code snippet, only the JSFiddle. So where you've got this:

```
var finalValue = $('#test').val();
var testInput = test();
if(testInput){
     $('span').text(finalValue);
}
```

It instead needs to be this:

```
var testInput = test();
if(testInput){
    var finalValue = $('#test').val();
     $('span').text(finalValue);
}
```

Note the movement of setting `finalValue` to be *after* the call to `test()`.

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bQSA3/4/

Perhaps where you were mistaken was thinking the call to `$('#test').val()` set a *reference* to the value of the `test` input. It instead gets a *copy* of the value. If the value in `test` changes, you need to fetch the value again.

Answer (score 9):

You can set a default value for your print out

```
var finalValue = $('#test').val() || 0;
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/odiseo/bQSA3/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this...

```
if(!this.value){this.val(0);}
```

Comment: TypeError: this.val is not a function and if(!this.value){jQuery(this).val(0);} does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Ok, then maybe wrap this in the jquery function...
Try putting this instead...

    if(!this.value){jQuery(this).val(0);}

Comment: How about setting the value to zero using the .attr() function? Maybe that would work...  if(!this.value){jQuery(this).attr("value",0);}

Comment: same issue check this fiddle for the exact problem i am having: http://jsfiddle.net/bQSA3/3/

Answer (score 0):

The below code (simplified) always displays **true** in *alert*, which I think is the expected behavior.

**Html**

```
<form id="carloan-form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <button id="check">check</button>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    $("#check").click(function() {
        var result = true;
        jQuery("#carloan-form :input[type=text]").each(function() {
            if(!this.value){this.value = 0;}

            if(jQuery.isNumeric(this.value) && this.value>=0) {

            }else{
                result = false;
            }
        });

        alert(result);
    });
});
```